# spring data lazy loading

Tags: jpa, lazy-evaluation, spring-data, lazy-initialization

I use spring data, jpa and hibernate

I have a Advertisement class

```
@Entity
public class Advertisement implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="id", cascade={CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  private Set<Message> messages = new HashSet<Message>();
}
```

and a message class

```
@Entity
public class Message implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Advertisement advertisement;
}
```

when i search an Advertisement by id, i can see all their message... i don't understand why, i put lazy...

I search a way to load Advertisement without message.

Comment: What do you mean by I can see all their message?  Do you mean you see the SQL being generated or do you mean you iterate through the set?

Comment: in debug mode, i see message value is not null.

Comment: does it contain a proxy?

Comment: don't know, but spring data use proxy to generate query

Comment: Lazy loaded entities are often loaded into the list as a proxy.  Just because the `Set` does not contain null values does not mean that Hibernate queried and loaded the objects.

Comment: i put show sql (hibernate) to true, but i only see insert sql... not select sql

Comment: That would indicate that they are being lazy loaded.

Comment: ok i found strange i can't see any select... i want to be sure

Comment: It might also be that when debugger hits the lazy list, it will cause hibernate to load the lazy collection if a session is still available. If session is not available at that point, you will get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are not loading the messages until you call it.